# Handling mousePressEvent for overlapping graphics items

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I have two different classes inheriting `QGraphicsItem`. Both of them have their specific `mousePressEvent` functions. When these items overlap on the scene, I want to execute only one of the items' `mousePressEvent`. How can I achieve this?

```
void PpiTargetItem::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event) {
    mTargetColor = Qt::red;
    event->setAccepted(true);
}

// Bigger Item
void CriticalRegion::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event) {
    LOGGER_START
    mCorners[0] = new CornerGrabber(this, 0);
    mCorners[1] = new CornerGrabber(this, 1);
    mCorners[2] = new CornerGrabber(this, 2);
    mCorners[3] = new CornerGrabber(this, 3);

    mCorners[0]->installSceneEventFilter(this);
    mCorners[1]->installSceneEventFilter(this);
    mCorners[2]->installSceneEventFilter(this);
    mCorners[3]->installSceneEventFilter(this);

    setCornerPositions();
    event->setAccepted(true);
    LOGGER_END
}
```

Comment: have one accept the event

Comment: By the way, there is a sceneEventFilter() in one of the items (no mousePressEvent function) and I think it might be preventing the other item to take mousePress events.

Answer (score 1):

When you inherit from QGraphicsItem and implement the function

```
void QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event)
```

Call **event->accept()** when the object wanting to deal with the event has done so.
If this doesn't work for you, please add example code to your question.

Comment: Same problem also exists for hoverEnter and hoverLeaveEvent functions. Both items have these functions and they only work for the bigger item. Small item that resides in the big item does not take any events. I have already been calling event->setAccepted(true)

Comment: @fatma.ekici what if you call `setAccepted(false)` for the larger item? Will smaller item get events? I suspect that Qt performs the hit test on your items and choose the larger item as being "on top" of a smaller one.

Comment: Problem solved. I noticed that Z value of those two items are the same. I increased the Z value of the item whose mouseEvent is to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

1- Set zValue of Grpahics
2- accept the event by calling :
**event->accept()**

and do not call base class event like :

**CriticalRegion::hoverEnterEvent(event)**